# Правило, запрещающее давать ответы с собственным плагином

Tags: обсуждение

Недавно столкнулся с такой ситуацией: Задал вопрос и написал ответ на тему "JS. Как сделать анимацию без JQuery". Перед подачей вопроса/ответа я убедился, что подобного вопроса с решением - нет. В ответе сделал акцент на использовании плагина, который написал я и, согласен, это выглядело как реклама. Ответ сразу же получил кучу минусов.

После того, как я отредактировал акцент в ответе на решение вопроса с помощью JS, а в конце просто предложил вариант с использованием плагина и указал ссылку на <s>PornHub</s> GitHub. После этой правки я получил ещё несколько минусов, притом, теперь и на вопрос.

Когда я спросил, что за, как бы мягко выразиться, хрень, то мне ответили, что я могу в ответе указывать ссылку на любой плагин, но только не на свой.

Так вот у меня возник вопрос: по какой такой причине и по какому правилу мне запрещается делиться знаниями и вариантами по решению вопроса? Почему я не могу предложить использовать свой плагин, если у меня такой есть? Может этот вариант понравится нескольким десяткам пользователей и поможет им решить свою проблему? Разве не в этом суть этого... сайта?

К тому же, мне понравилось другое: я уже когда-то публиковал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/700228/20458), который посвящён решению вопроса с помощью своего плагина. И мне ничего не сказали по этому поводу и даже поставили 1 плюс.

Ссылка на ситуацию: [Анимация без использования JQuery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706288/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-jquery)

---

<sup>Вангую: у этого вопроса будет достаточно много минусов :)</sup>

Comment: Ответ после правки выглядит нормально, imho. Скорее всего минусовали по инерции. Стоило просто ответить на коммент Алексея после внесения правки, чтобы было видно, что коммент относится к старой редакции ответа - это, скорее всего, остановило бы минусы.

Comment: @PashaPash, но даже после последней правки, ваш коллега Nofate сделал правку, в которой удалил часть ответа, что касается решения вопроса плагином

Comment: тогда стоит подождать ответа от Nofate. модераторы тоже иногда ошибаются

Comment: @Yuri, вы вернули ссылку и повторно упустили важную деталь: укажите явно, что это **ваш** плагин (о чем D-Side еще в чате сказал).

Comment: @Nofate, уже отредактировал ответ, где указал, что это мой плагин

Comment: @Yuri теперь хорошо, вернул голос

Comment: Мне на других форумах встречались сообщения, что на SO банили тех, кто даёт ответы с использованием своих библиотек. Типа за рекламу. Так что, есть повод волноваться.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Можно. А судя по [enSO](//stackoverflow.com/a/40327335/4928642) даже так можно:

> I took the advice from Bergi's answer and wrapped it into an [NPM module](https://github.com/cgamesplay/node-callable-instance).

> Я последовал совету из ответа Bergi и сделал [NPM модуль](https://github.com/cgamesplay/node-callable-instance)

И дальше пример использования.

Comment: Более того: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: @Андрей там немного о другом. Но изначально ответ был направлен именно на рекламу, а не на что-то еще. Отсюда и возникшая проблема.

Comment: @Qwertiy я так понимаю в вопросе по ссылке, которую ты указал суть в том, что все решения не совсем тривиальны и не имеют популярно информации об этом. В вопросе же ТС наоборот - есть достаточно популярный инструмент, который всем знаком и о котором и нужно было рассказать. Вместо этого был этот инструмент упомянут вскользь парой слов и кинута ссылка на статью, а дальше слоган "Пользуйтесь моим плагином" и понеслася)) Так что тут надо различать почему, к чему и как

Answer (score 10):

Общее правило: если у вас есть какая-либо связь с проектом или продуктом, на который вы даёте ссылку, это **нужно явно указать в сообщении**. Всё. Это требование выставляется, чтобы дать посетителям полную информацию: мнение о проекте или продукте может быть предвзятым, однобоким и так далее, однако оно всё равно имеет право на существование.

Также, если даёте ссылку, то требуется указать, что по этой ссылке находится, почему именно оно полезно, возможно, процитировать какую-то часть или целиком. Это общее правило, касающееся запрета голых ответов-ссылок. (Это к вам не относится, так, для полноты картины.)

Создавать отдельный вопрос под свой проект — не самый рациональный ход, потому что это может раздражать участников. Отсюда минусы. Лучше не палиться и вместо этого попробовать найти уже существующий вопрос. Предложить альтернативное решение — тоже вариант.

На большом SO у меня несколько ответов, рекламирующих YaLinqo, в том числе [ответ с 19 плюсами](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30654346). Какие-то ответы ловили и минусы, но обычно выходили в плюс. В конечном счёте ответ должен помогать.